# Where does a question about tweaking / tuning a software belongs to?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, migration, asking-questions

Where does the question like "How do I run 2 instances of a < software > on Live machine?"

or

"How can I run 2 instances of same software but different versions?"

My question was on ServerFault : https://serverfault.com/questions/485120/how-to-create-a-portable-php-install-of-a-different-version-from-that-used-by-th
was closed as Off-Topic

and question on Programmers https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189724/how-to-create-a-portable-php-5-4-install was voted to be moved to SO.

and on SO, I am sure, it will be closed because there will be a first comment "What have you tried?"

Please help me navigate this question to get the right response.

Many thanks.

Comment: If reasonably scoped you can ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Umm... I checked the questions and answers being asked.. They are fit for day to day questions but, not something like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a lot of this going around. If it's in a professional level, it belongs on Server Fault. If it's something that's unlikely to be on a production server - it's for personal development use , you could probably ask on Super User. Small scale server stuff *is* a grey area, and at some point, I think SU and SF need to sit down and work out something on this.

However, "What have you tried?" will be asked anywhere. Stack Exchange isn't a replacement for research effort. I also note the question on [Software Engineering site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) lacks details.

Tell us a story. Tell us why you *really* need two versions of PHP, and mention what you've considered or tried so far. Make us see why this install needs to be portable (and what is portable here? Between installs on identical systems with the same OS? Any Linux system?). Make the question something your audience will look at and go *oooh*, and it's less likely to be closed. You need to show both that you've tried to solve the problem, and add more cowbell to the question to get attention.

I've not tried it myself, but a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=side%20by%20side%20installs%20of%20PHP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) [suggested this as a method](http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server) - so clearly this isn't an unanswerable question, but one where a little more research could get you started. You will then have a better chance of asking a question to fix minor issues *and* not have it closed.

Comment: Fortunately, its on SO...

Comment: Thanks for the link... It is worth a look... Will see if this issue can be resolved with some tweaks... overall, thanks a lot :)